# Firebase Admin failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token - unable to verify certificate

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-oauth, firebase-admin

Any help appreciated.

Currently developing on localhost.
Date and time are in sync.
Latest firebase-admin installed.

This was working absolutely fine one day and not the next. (No changes).

Terminal output:
`@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"unable to verify the first certificate\"."}`

This is the begining of the `app.js`:

```
//requires
var radius = require("radius");
var dgram = require("dgram");
var admin = require("firebase-admin");    

//for CHAP hashing
var crypto = require("crypto");

//Load additional radius dictionaries
radius.add_dictionary('./radius_dictionaries');

//init firebase
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://<database>.firebaseio.com/"
});
//init db object
var db = admin.database();
```

This app does not present an *HTTPS* webpage, or and *HTTPS* end point for http requests. Simply connects to the Firebase database and reads data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Started a clean app and had an issue where I couldn't even install `firebase-admin`.

With a bit of digging I noticed that `node-pre-gyp` was throwing alot of stack errors while trying to build, and node couldn't find my local python install (despite being installed).

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with 
exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit 
(C:\Users\Jonth\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node- 
gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
```

And certificate errors again

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error unable to verify the first certificate
```

So what I did to fix the issue was:

**RUN**

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

**AND RUN**

*This is what really fixed the issue*

```
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

I can now run my app and continue with development.
Why I needed to do this I don't honestly know.
If someone could enlighten me, I'm all ears.
I can only hope this doesn't effect my app when it gets deployed to the Google cloud.

*FYI, development PC is Windows 10 Pro*

Comment: Looks like something to do with the certificate chain / root certificate available for NPM on Windows. This might be related: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8872